# Add values inside same class and return the sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello people here is my code below...

```
var total = 0;
var find_total;
 function total_val(find_total){

$(find_total).each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
    return total;
});

  }
```

Iam calling this function...

```
$('#total_price').val(total_val('.price'));
```

`#total_price` and `.price` keeps changing for `different div ids and class` ... `return total;` does not work, any ways to fix this??

Comment: You're not returning anything to the outer function.

Comment: @Friend can you share the html code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the total value inside the `.each()` function, it would not return anything while we expecting a value from the function `total_val()`,

Try,

```
function total_val(find_total){ 
   var total = 0; //remove the global variable total and use this.
   $(find_total).each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
   });
   return total;
}
```

or you could use `.reduce()` to make your code simple.

```
function total_val(find_total){ 
   return $(find_total).map(function() {
   return parseInt($(this).text());
   }).get().reduce(function(a,b){
   return a+b;
   });
}
```

Even simpler,

```
function total_val(find_total){ 
   return $(find_total).get().reduce(function(a,b){
      return a+ parseInt($(b).text(),10);
   },0);
}
```

Comment: The map and reduce can be done in the same step; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319956/jquery-add-values-inside-same-class-and-return-the-sum/#24320030) for more details.

Comment: `ReferenceError: total is not defined` (for your first answer)

Comment: @maček See here.. http://jsfiddle.net/L9RJh/1/ where did you find the error.? OP has declared the total as global one.. Have you noticed that in his question..?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle showing you a couple ways you can do this](http://jsfiddle.net/macek/L9RJh/).

This could work nicely for you

```
function total(jq, callback) {
  return jq.get().reduce(function (sum, elem) {
    return sum + window.parseInt(callback(elem), 10);
  }, 0);
}
```

Then use it like this

```
total($(".price"), function(elem) {
  return $(elem).text();
});
```

---

I think this approach is nicer because it gives you flexibility over the type of elements you could be `total`-ing.

For example, if you were trying to total `<input>` elements, you would want this instead

```
total($("input"), function(elem) {
  return $(elem).val();
});
```

---

Even better, make it into a lightweight jQuery plugin like this

```
(function(window, $) {
  function total(jq, callback) {
    // code from above
  }

  $.fn.total = function(callback) {
    return total(this, callback);
  };
})(window, jQuery);
```

Now you can use it like this

```
$(".price").total(function(elem) {
  return $(elem).text();
});
```